Filtering QGIS atlas output by later groups
I have a QGIS project that has layers arranged in groups.  I want to generate an atlas that will produce a separate map for each group based on the layers.
I would also like to include a legend that relates only to the specific layers.
My coverage layer has a field that that holds the names of each group.
I am using QGIS 3.34.4 Prizen

Not exactly sure what you mean. Maybe Map themes? See https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#configuring-map-themes Layer groups can't be directly accessed as far as I know (at least not without programming).
